# Could devices on one circuit affect devices on another?

Tags: switches, circuit-design

I recently swapped out some light switches on an electrical circuit in my home.  Ever since then, I’ve noticed some slight flickering of the fixed lighting which resides on a separate circuit in the home.  I was under the impression that each circuit was entirely isolated from one another.  Is this true?

Comment: "entirely isolated"? What makes you think that?

Comment: Check how many electrical supplies you have coming into your home. (The answer is probably "one".) If you have only one then all circuits in your home are in parallel. They are also in parallel with others on your street fed from the same distribution transformer. The circuits can be isolated from each other (up to a point) by switching off the circuit breaker. Generally the neutral wires will still be connected.

Comment: Brian it depends what kind of switch and lights you have. 100W tungsten or Halogen lamps draw about 1kW during startup.  Often ceiling and wall sockets can be shared in 2 rooms to make up 15A or 20A and the surge can cause some lights to flicker especially if sensitive to voltage transients like some LED potlights.  I had a timer switch in the bathroom fan cause my next room PC monitor to blink whenever the fan shutoff. So I put a tiny plastic leaded cap across the switch to suppress the transient, meaning it can be conducted or radiated glitch.